# mongo db very slow to insert documents on CentOs vs Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, centos7

did any one experience very bad performance to insert documents into mongo db on CentOs vs Ubuntu

i'm using mongo version 2.4.9 and running following command on mongo shell on empty DB:

```
start = new Date(); 
for(var i=0;i<100000;i++){db.test.insert({a:1+i, b:i+2, c:i+3, d:i+4, e: [1,2,3,4,5,6,i]}); } 
end = new Date(); 
print(end - start);
```

this operation takes about 4.6 seconds on Ubuntu, and about 36 seconds on CentOs 
note that both Os running as guest OS, using windows based Virtual Box as host, while configured to run using 2 cores, hardware virtualization enabled, 7 GB memory on same physical machine, 25 GB disc
also the Operating system is not occupied with any other tasks.
during test, we saw that CPU utilization on CenOs was bad(only one core working at specific time), while on Ubuntu, both cores were used in parallel